# Error while using Octokit.NET to authenticate users from Web App

Tags: asp.net, .net, oauth, github-api, octokit.net

I'm using Octokit to authenticate a user from my app. I'm successfully getting the Code and State parameters back from Github. But when I try to create an access token, it throws an exception. What am i doing wrong?

Here is the code in my Authorize function -

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Authorize(string code, string state)
    {
       var req = new OauthTokenRequest(clientId, clientSecret, code);
       var token = await client.Oauth.CreateAccessToken(req);
       Session["OAuthToken"] = token.AccessToken;
    }
```

I get a very generic error - "An error occured with this API request".

Answer (score 0):

Start adding an exception handling in order to get more information from the exception (at least to catch [`Octokit.ApiException`](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/7fe4c4ee905bf4ba36ebbae59ca8c01c05b18e4a/Octokit/Exceptions/ApiException.cs#L16)):

```cs
try
{
    var req = new OauthTokenRequest(clientId, clientSecret, code);
    var token = await client.Oauth.CreateAccessToken(req);
    Session["OAuthToken"] = token.AccessToken;
}
catch (Octokit.ApiException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ApiError.Message);
    foreach(var error in ex.ApiError.Errors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
    }
}
```